# Sort list of lists with groupby and count

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking to do a sort of a list of lists. My function needs to return the day that that fewest activity of a certain type and if there is a tie, return the day with the fewest overall activities. Below is a working solution but I feel like it's fairly unpythonic as it needs to convert to a dictionary and back to a list and am looking for a faster way to write this.

`print get_day(mylist, 'Activity C')` should yield `Day 1`

`print get_day(mylist, 'Activity A')` should yield `Day 2`

```
def get_day(l, activity):
    d = {}

    for x in l:
        if x[0] not in d.keys():
            d[x[0]] = []
        d[x[0]].append(x[1])

    d = {k: [v.count(activity), len(v)] for k, v in d.items()}

    l = [[k, v[0], v[1]] for k, v in d.items()]

    l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
    return l[0][0]


mylist = [['Day 1', 'Activity A'], ['Day 2', 'Activity A'], ['Day 1', 'Activity A'], ['Day 2', 'Activity C'],
          ['Day 2', 'Activity D']]
```

Comment: Why `get_day(mylist, 'Activity C')` should yield `Day 1` ?

Comment: @RafaelC Day 1 has no activity of type C. Since the function first needs to sort by a group by of that activity type, then by count of total activities.

Comment: what should we do in case when there are equal target activity & overall activities counts?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov in that case it doesn't matter, so one of the two can be arbitrarily picked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't guarantee speed here without knowing more about the expected input dimensions and use case, but I think this code is more pythonic.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def get_day_pythonic(lst, activity):
    if not lst:
        return
    # Count of activities by day
    day_act_counts = Counter([d for (d, a) in lst])
    # Activity counts per day
    act_counter = defaultdict(Counter)
    for (d, a) in lst:
        act_counter[a][d] += 1
    # NOTE: if planning to call this multiple times, should precompute day_act_counts and act_counter.
    # Here we sort first by lowest count of activity, then total activity counts, and then day name.
    return sorted([(act_counter[activity][d], day_act_counts[d], d) for d in day_act_counts])[0][-1]
```

EDIT: Faster implementation

```
def get_day(lst, activity):
     if not lst:
         return
     # Count of all activities by day
     day_act_counts = {}
     # Count of interested activity by day
     act_counter = {}
     for (d, a) in lst:
         day_act_counts[d] = day_act_counts.get(d, 0) + 1
         if a != activity:  # don't need exact count for other activities
             continue
         act_counter[d] = act_counter.get(d, 0) + 1
     # Here we take the min first by lowest count of activity, then total activity counts, and then day name.
     return min((act_counter.get(d, 0), day_act_counts[d], d) for d in day_act_counts)[-1]
```

Comment: this is a very nice clean approach, but unfortunately a bit slow. Using timeit with the data provided, this method is about twice as slow (even precompiled).

Comment: If speed is what you're after, I'd suggest precomputing an underlying activity count data structure and then making the query. Updated my answer to include an approach that is 4x faster than my original answer provided on the example.

Answer (score 1):

First we can write utility for collecting pairs by first coordinate:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def collect(items):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in items:
        result[key].append(value)
    return result
```

After that our `get_day` function can be written like

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import imap


def get_day(days_activities, target_activity):
    activities_by_days = collect(days_activities)
    days_by_activities = collect(imap(reversed, days_activities))
    days_target_activity_counter = Counter(days_by_activities[target_activity])

    def to_target_and_overall_activities_counts(day):
        return (days_target_activity_counter[day],
                #  if there is a tie
                len(activities_by_days[day]))

    return min(activities_by_days,
               key=to_target_and_overall_activities_counts)
```

## Test

```
# 'Day 1' has fewest overall activities (3 < 4)
>>> mylist = [['Day 1', 'Activity A'],
              ['Day 1', 'Activity A'],
              ['Day 2', 'Activity A'],
              ['Day 2', 'Activity C'],
              ['Day 1', 'Activity D'],
              ['Day 2', 'Activity D'],
              ['Day 2', 'Activity E']]
>>> get_day(mylist, 'Activity C')
'Day 1'
>>> get_day(mylist, 'Activity A')
'Day 2'
>>> get_day(mylist, 'Activity D')
'Day 1'
```